# Spring JPA Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am encountering some strange behavior in Spring managed transactions. This a Spring MVC app. I am binding entities directly to the Web tier. I load a persistent entity from the database for edit using the following service layer code which is called from a method annotated with @ModelAttribute.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@PreAuthorize("#id == authentication.principal.id or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public User findById(Long id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}
```

When the form is submitted the data is bound to this detached entity. As part of validation I query the database to validate that the email address specified for the User is unique.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean isEmailAddressUnique(String emailAddress, Long userId){
    return repository.checkEmailAddressUnique(emailAddress, userId) == 0;
}
```

At this point, before executing this query, Hibernate attempts to flush the previously loaded detached entity which I don't understand. Obviously this results in an Exception if the email address is not unique.

I am using the OpenEntityManagerinViewFilter however I would expect that this should have FlushMode set to NEVER, perhaps not.

If I remove the @Transactional attribute from the isEmailAddressUnique() the flush does not occur and verything works as expected which I suppose solves the issue however I would like to understand what is going on here.

Any suggestions?

=============

Okay, I have investigated further. So I have OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter configured with defaults:

Scenario One.

[1] MVC Controller loads A User entity in a readOnly transaction T1
[2] Entity is modified as a result of MVC field binding
[3] Second transaction runs against Users table in a readOnly transaction T2.
[4] Hibernate flushes the entity loaded in T1.
[5] Hibernate issues the query

Scenario 2.

Subclassed the OEMIVFilter to set the FlushMode to commit (default is auto).

As above with steps [4] and [5] reversed, viz. even though T2 is marked as readOnly Hibernate still attempts to Flush at the end of the transaction. I could understand scenario 1 as readOnly may only refer to the current transaction T2 (and will attempt to synchronize the database before executing T2). However I would expect that in scenario 2 no Flush should be issued.

Comment: Having thought about this a bit more I suppose it makes sense in that each transaction is bound to the same Hibernate session, viz.  that bound to the request by the OEMIV Filter. This however seems a bit dangerous in that changes can be flushed to the database without explicitly reattaching and saving the entity. The OpenSessionViewFilter allowed specifying singleSession false which seems to me to address the issue by having each transaction bound to its own session however I do not see a similar setting for OpenEntityManagerInView filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in the beginning. We also use the OSIV filter and the problem in our case was that the readonly flag on the transactional annotation was not propagated to hibernate. We had to ensure that we use the propere transactionmanager and more important the hibernatevendoradapter.
Check your config for this and if you cannot solve the issue post your persistence and spring integration configs.

Comment: Hi Martin. I am not familiar with HibernateVendorAdapter. Can you provide any further information about how it is configured and what it does? Thanks.

Comment: YES Martin. You are correct! The issue was that I had not specified a the JPAVendorAdaptor for the EMF. Everything else appeared to work correctly without this. The funny thing is I copied the initial JPA config from a sample project I had generated using Spring Roo. The Roo generated file did not specify an adapter but does automatically configure the OEMIV Filter. So I guess anyone bootstrapping  a project using Roo may experience the same behaviour. Any, thanks again. Been driving me mad.